# About event dispatch thread

Tags: java, event-dispatch-thread

I’m reading some articles about Event Dispatch Thread  in java. As  it implies  the creation of GUI and all the events of GUI components  should performed within this thread . if take a look at some code which generate on net beans IDE when create a JFrame I can agree with a part of this  comment. Because  it includes some code that direct the GUI creation to the EDT like **java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()..**...

```
Ex:
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Temp().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

But expressions that we write on events  handling methods does not have that kind of directing statements.

```
Ex
private void btnTodayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ;
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
}
```

Where is that? Or is it done by the compiler??
Please be kind to help me .. this will be some silly question…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events are always raised on the EDT, so any code you write for your callback is also on the EDT, you only need invokeLater (or similar) when you are already using a different thread (for example, long tasks should not be performed on the EDT because they freeze up the entire interface, instead they should be executed on their own thread and periodically use invokeLater to update the interface)

Answer (score 1):

As the name implies, all UI events, including click events, are raised on the **event** dispatch thread.

What the event dispatch thread actually does is run an OS-level message loop to be notified of UI events, then dispatch those events to the appropriate Swing components.